# I am not sure how to solve this Parse error: syntax error in php

Tags: php

I get the below error message when I try to run the attached code.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\chain_gang\private\classes\bicycle.class.php on line 20`

This is line 20

```
protected const CONDITION_OPTIONS = [
1 => 'Beat up',
2 => 'Decent',
3 => 'Good',
4 => 'Great',
5 => 'Like New'
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your PHP version?

If you are using PHP v<7, [you can't declare a constant as an array.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

Answer (score 0):

Constants are by default Global scope you can't set access specifier with them such as protected. If you use the same constant on 2 classes and call them in a single function they will create error.